# why I always get singleton bean, even if I use proxyBeanMethods = false?

Tags: java, spring-boot

now I am learning SpringBoot. really got confused about the annotation `@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)`

I defined an configuration class like the following,

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class BeanConfiguration {
    @Bean("User")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "user2")
    public User getUser(){
        return  new User();
    }
}
```

I thought every bean will be different, cause it doesn't work in singleton mode.

but the test code shows me a different idea.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Boot2InitializrApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(Boot2InitializrApplication.class, args);

        User user1 = (User)applicationContext.getBean(User.class);
        User user2 = (User)applicationContext.getBean(User.class);

        System.out.println((user1 == user2));   **//here ? always true.  even if I set 'proxyBeanMethods = false' .** 



        BeanConfiguration bean = applicationContext.getBean(BeanConfiguration.class);
        User user3 = bean.getUser();
        User user4 = bean.getUser();
        System.out.println(user3==user4);  //here, it varies when proxyBeanMethods is set true or/false.    

    }

}
```

Why does the bean I get through applicationContext always work under singleton mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html#proxyBeanMethods--) that is actually the expected behavior:

> Specify whether @Bean methods should get proxied in order to enforce bean lifecycle behavior, e.g. to return shared singleton bean instances even in case of direct @Bean method calls in user code.

This means that `@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)` has only an effect when you call `getUser()` method directly, hence `System.out.println((user1 == user2));` is always true because you are not calling the `@Bean` method directly but instead relying on Spring to return to you the needed Bean (which will be the same since Spring-managed Beans are Singleton by default).

Regarding `System.out.println(user3==user4)` it will be true when you use `@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = true)`, because this means that Spring-managed Beans lifecycle will be enforced and thus even if you call `getUser()` method directly, it will return the same Bean. It will return false if you use `@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)`, because by then Spring-managed Beans lifecycle will not be enforced and a brand new `User` will be created and returned.

Comment: Do you know how to set `proxyBeanMethods = false` for the entire application?

Comment: Sorry @bjmi, I don't know if that is possible.